# how can i know the current java.policy in effect

Tags: java, security, administrator

I read from [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html), the default location of java.policy is

```
java.home\lib\security\java.policy
```

and user location is

```
user.home\.java.policy
```

But I also notice that a path in my Windows

```
C:\Users\<<myid>>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security
```

I like to edit java policy file in different location. How can I show the current java policy in effective?

```
For example, type java.exe --show_me_all_permission_granted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Java with

```
-Djava.security.debug=access,failure,policy
```

You will see all access failures and the protection domain for each, including its policy file source, and the permissions assigned from each policy file.

Comment: oic, so I can edit policy files in different location, to test the policy file precedence, But it will be better if I can know the policy list at the end.

Comment: You will see all that from the output of the option I gave.